# Как сделать меню android

Tags: android

В приложении сверху должны быть 2 линии меню, как на скрине ниже.
Подскажите, это делается через фрагменты?

Например:

- первый фрагмент - верхняя полоска меню
- второй фрагмент - нижняя полоска меню
- трейтий фрагмент - контент

Или обе полосы как-то в ActionBar можно запихнуть?

[image: Меню]

Comment: 1 - toolbar, 2 - tabLayout, 3 - fragment

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Для такого меню испоььзуется tabLayout, здесь есть пример https://www.google.ru/amp/s/android-tools.ru/coding/delaem-vkladki-s-pomoshhyu-tablayout/amp/